# UPS Magento 2.3 when generate shipping label then getting error this "Failed to send items"

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, ups

1 - Using Magento 2.3.3 UPS Shipping

2 - we are able to get the Shipping Rates at checkout.

3 - when we are trying to create shipping label from admin then it gives an error like this - "Failed to send items"

This is screenshot.
[image]

Please let us know if anyone has face this type of error.

Answer (score 2):

I found my solution (yours may be different). For us the problem was that the name used on the site did not match the name (or nickname) used in UPS.

Name on site is found at: Stores > Configuration > General > General > Store Information > Store Name.

I'm guessing that the address may need to match as well.

How I found that info... was to edit the following file: (Magento root) > vendor > magento > module-ups > Model > Carrier.php

find this line (around 1831):

```
return new DataObject(['errors' => __('Failed to send items... ')]);
```

and change to:

```
return new DataObject(['errors' => __('Failed to send items... '.$exception)]);
```

... then when you try to "save" to get the label, this will print out the exception and towards the top you may see what the "real" error message is.

Comment: Thank you for this, it saved us a lot of time trying to debug this. In our case, the error was caused by the Shippers shipper number not being enabled by UPS. Thanks a lot again!